# Struct function pointer error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

In the struct my_struct, there is a function pointer called compute(). It is declared as such:

```
struct my_struct
{
  double (*compute) (double input);
}
```

In a separate file, I initialize that struct so I can point that function to another one.

```
static const struct my_struct data;
data.compute = ......
```

The problem is, no matter what I set the function pointer to, I get the following error for data.compute:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

I've used data members of structs plenty of times using the '.' operator, but I've never used function pointers. Is there something different needed here?

Comment: It should work notationally, though since you've defined the structure as `const`, you can only initialize it and not assign to it after initialization.  However, that's a different error from the one you're getting.  It's behaving as if `data` isn't a simple word — as if it is macro expanded into something odd, or something along those lines.  The structure type is declared in a header, isn't it?  And it does have a semicolon after the `}`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, const isn't the problem. I've tried removing it, only to get the same error. Any idea how to solve that last part you're talking about?

Comment: Not enough code — you've not provided an MCVE ([MCVE]) — we have no code that we can compile and see the error you're seeing (or something similar).  We'd need your header and a minimal set of code that shows the problem.  You are writing the `data.compute = …` inside a function, aren't you?  (_Hmmm: I suspect not_ — you must either use initialization `… data = { … };` or move the assignment inside a function.)

Comment: No, it's not in a function. Could you elaborate a little more on … data = { … };? I don't recognize that syntax, what does the first ... represent?

Comment: The first `…` is `static const struct my_struct` but I was feeling too lazy to copy'n'paste.  So, you need: `static const struct my_struct data = { .compute = sin };` or something similar (`static const struct my_struct data = { sin };` if you are stuck without a C99 or later compiler).  You can't write assignments outside of functions — that is your problem.  I'll make an answer.

Comment: Hm, the fact that I can't do this outside of a function is troubling. I need this to be a global declaration. I thought for sure there was a way to do that

Comment: There is — it's called initialization.  But this is C so there are limits on what you can use as an initializer.  It must be evaluable by the compiler; it must not need runtime computation.  What's the difficulty?

Comment: You mean like you just described? I tried that and got the error "undeclared here (not in a function)". I thought ... data = {...} was considered initialization

Comment: Well, I did kinda assume (and we know that 'assume' makes an 'ass' of 'u' and 'me') that you knew that the `sin()` function is declared in the `<math.h>` header.

Comment: No, I wasn't using sin. I'm actually using a different function of my own defined in that file (the file where this struct 'data' is initialized). So it's ... data = {.compute = distance};

Comment: OK; as long as you've already declared (or defined) `distance` before you try to use it in the initializer, you should be OK.  If you have declared it yet you still have compiler errors, drop the 'designated initializer' notation (the `.compute =` part, leaving just `distance`).  That should work with any C compiler worthy of the name (pre-standard, C90, C99, C11).

Comment: Okay this might seem like a stupid question, but if the function distance() is defined before I initialize 'data', would 'data' still be considered a global variable? I ask because I'm so used to global variables being declared at the top of the code, just after the header stuff

Comment: A global variable is defined outside of any function and without the keyword `static`.  You can have functions before you define a global variable; you can have other variables defined before it.  You can have the global variable defined as the last thing in the source file — but then you can't reference it in the same source file unless there's an `extern` declaration before you attempt to reference it.  The compiler must be told that `distance` is a function before you mention it in the initializer.  One way or another, the compiler must know about the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work notationally, though since you've defined the structure as `const`, you can only initialize it and not assign to it after initialization.

However, that's a different error from the one you're getting. It's behaving a bit as if `data` isn't a simple word — as if it is macro expanded into something odd, or something along those lines. The structure type is declared in a header, isn't it? And it does have a semicolon after the }, doesn't it?

> Yeah, `const` isn't the problem. I've tried removing it, only to get the same error. Any idea how to solve that last part you're talking about?

At one level, there's not enough code — you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — we have no code that we can compile and see the error you're seeing (or something similar). We'd need your header and a minimal set of code that shows the problem.

You are writing the `data.compute = …` inside a function, aren't you? (*Hmmm: I suspect not* — you must either use initialization `… data = { … };` or move the assignment inside a function.)

> No, it's not in a function. Could you elaborate a little more on `… data = { … };`? I don't recognize that syntax; what does the first `…` represent?

The first `…` is `static const struct my_struct` but I was feeling too lazy to copy'n'paste. So, you need:

```
static const struct my_struct data = { .compute = sin };
```

or something similar (assuming you include the `<math.h>` to provide a declaration for `sin` — or use some other function that you've already declared or defined).  If you are stuck without a C99 or later compiler):

```
static const struct my_struct data = { sin };
```

You can't write assignments outside of functions — that is your problem. You must use an initializer, or write the assignment inside a function and remove the `const`.